# Restart app to a certain activity?

Tags: android, restart

I need to restart my app to a certain activity...is it possible?

When I restart it I don't want to start the first activity of application. How can I do this?

EDIT : I need to free memory of the app when I restart the app.

Answer (score 2):

In the onCreate method of the activity that is first launched you need to check if you want to go to another activity or not and then

where restarted is some condition that check if your app was running before , you can use shared preferences to store some bool value

```
if(restarted){

        Intent startActivity = new Intent();
        startActivity.setClass(this,OTHER_ACTIVITY.class);
        startActivity(startActivity); 
        finish();
}else{
   //just normal flow
}
```

Comment: this mean that it frees the memory of app?

Comment: This is basically a pattern for 'resuming' an Activity. Whenever you start a new activity, the classname is put into a SharedPreference value. Then when the user re-launches the app at a later date, your first 'starter' activity starts the last known activity.

Comment: The memory it is not 'freezed', the app is started again but with different flow. If you want some variables to be saved in memory permanently use shared preferences

Comment: For me is important to free the memory...for this I want to restart the app

Comment: all your instance variables will be freed! of course this will happen if you allocate them in activity A and than close this activity A

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the `Activity` you wish straight from the initial `Activity`'s `onCreate()`. As this is only applicable when the app restarts, you have to save a `SharedPreference` to flag the fact your app has already started once.

There won't be any flickering as `Activity` is designed in a way it is not displayed if another `Activity` is started during its `onCreate()`.