# How to restart the application or return the LAUNCHER page in Preferences Activity?

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restart app to a certain activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308324/restart-app-to-a-certain-activity)

I am currently writing an DialogPreferences Activity to delete the user account. I completely deleted the user data successfully and now planning to return to the LAUNCHER screen in order to push the user make a new installation. But I really couldn't find any way to return.

Intent is only usable from XML file as far as I understand.

Is there any way to use StartActivity() or restart the application in DialogPreferences Activity?

```
    public class DeleteAccountActivity extends DialogPreference {

       public DeleteAccountActivity(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
          super(context, attrs);
       }

       @Override
       protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
          super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);
          if (positiveResult) {
             if (DEBUG)
                Log.d(0, DEBUG_TAG, "DeleteAccountActivity");

         try {
            ...

            boolean success = rest.deregister(request);
            if (success) {
               Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                              getContext().getResources().getText(R.string.successfully_deleted_account),
                              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPref.edit();
               editor.clear();
               editor.commit();

               Intent intent = new Intent();
               intent.setClass(this, A.class);
               StartActivity(intent); //error
               if (DEBUG)
                  Log.d(0, DEBUG_TAG, "Deleted the user account successfully.");
            }
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(0, DEBUG_TAG, "asd", e);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: no, it's not. startActivity() is not callable from Preferences Activity.

Comment: Aren't you trying to call `startActivity()` from some inner class? use `MyPrefActivity.this.startActivity()`;

Comment: Perhaps you should post your relevant code because PreferencesActivity has the [`startActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) method, here is an [example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-quick-preferences-tutorial.html). Perhaps you are trying to call `startActivity()` in a nested class, like an OnClickListener...

Comment: I am really sorry. I mean DialogPreferences Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(With your code sample I saw a solution right away, thanks for posting it!) Since [`startActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) is a member of the Context class, so simply use:

```
getContext().startActivity(...);
```

And of course, rather than call `getContext()` three or more times you should save a reference to it in a local or class variable.